# ImageIO_Malloc memory leak using ARC

Tags: memory-leaks, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

When Alloco a UIImage with the method [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @ "imagename" oftype: @ "png"]]] this is not released memory. 
When you leave the view remains in memory and is not destroyed

link to Instrument screenshot

http://imageshack.com/a/img809/9168/pbie.png

Please Help Me